# How to build iOS apps using react- native on window 10

Tags: react-native, build

I am new in react-native. I want to build an android and iOS application by using react-native. I used the Windows 10 to build the react-native project and it is ok when I run the android app using Android SDK or real device but cannot on iOS devices. I have researched this problem and know that I need to use macOS to run the iOS apps. Is it possible to build iOS apps using any iOS simulator on Windows 10?

Comment: First of all, we don't know what *window* is. I think you mean Microsoft Windows. Then no. It's not possible to build iOS apps on Windows. You will need a macOS machine for that.

Comment: yes, I am using window 10 to build the project

Answer (score 1):

for exporting ios apps you must have a MAC system(X-code) or you can do it in windows with VMvare that have a virtual Mac system ,and in next step you must have a developer account then other steps are simple :)

Comment: thank you for your reply. react-native require what version of mac OS? If i use VMWare I should create what version for mac OS?

Comment: actually you have to see version of x-code but i use MAC-Mojave and everything is working

Answer (score 1):

The best way to develop in react native if you did not have access to MAC OSX environment is to use [EXPO](https://expo.io/tools#cli) as it will ensured the app could run on android and iOS.

The second option would be using private cloud Mac like [MacStadium](https://www.macstadium.com).

Comment: thank for your reply, i am using react-native-image-crop-picker in my apps but expo not support this package.

Comment: I can build iOS apps use EXPO in windows 10?

Comment: yes, this is the instructions:
[Building Standalone Apps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#if-you-choose-to-build-for-ios)